# modifying data variable in vue.js using axios

Tags: javascript, html, vuejs2

Here is my script :

```
<html>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.0/axios.js"></script>

<body>


    <div id="app-3">
        <span v-if="seen">{{ textFromApi }}</span>
    </div>
    <br/>


    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var app3 = new Vue({
            el: '#app-3',
            data: {
                seen: true,
                textFromApi: "hello"
            },
            methods: {
                getData() {
                    return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
                },
            },
            created: function () {
                this.textFromApi = this.getData();
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to modify `this.textFromApi` from the call of this api: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1

but my `this.textFromApi` doesn't seems to update, any ideas why?

Here is a fiddle code: 
https://jsfiddle.net/bussiere/5t3v013o/

Edited from remark just below

Regards and thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[created()](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#created) is a [lifecycle hook](https://alligator.io/vuejs/component-lifecycle/), it should be at the same level as data, methods, computed etc. Not a child of methods (so if you nest created() in methods() it will never get executed unless you call the method).

You also don't do anything with the axios promise, you should process it using `then ()`.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.17.0/axios.js"></script>
<body>


    <div id="app-3">
        <span v-if="seen">{{ textFromApi }}</span>
    </div>
    <br/>


    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        var app3 = new Vue({
        el: '#app-3',
        data () {
                return {
                    seen: true,
                    textFromApi: { title: 'empty'}
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getData() {
                return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1').then(response => {
                   this.textFromApi = response.data
                })
            },
        },
        created: function () {
            this.getData();
        }
    })
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: if i'am not wrong still not working  : https://jsfiddle.net/bussiere/5t3v013o/ and edited but htanks

Comment: Axios needs a promise like this: https://jsfiddle.net/5t3v013o/1/ I also updated my answer to include the promise.